# Calculating pitch and roll with accelerations greater than +/- 1g

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, rotation, software

I'm looking to compute the pitch and roll of a device fitted with a three axis accelerometer when it is not at rest or moving at a constant velocity. Most applications I've seen so far are for stationary tilt sensing... genuinely stuck on this one! Aiming to use it for a python program I'm working on.

For a stationary case I have the following:

```
roll = np.arctan2(a_y, a_z) * 180/np.pi
pitch = np.arctan2(a_x, np.sign(a_z)*np.sqrt(np.power(a_y,2) + np.power(a_z,2)))*180/np.pi
```

Essentially I have a case where I need to find the linear vertical acceleration of a device with g subtracted from it. My initial idea was to use something along the lines of the following:

```
a_linear_z = a_measured_z - g*R
R = [-np.sin(pitch),np.cos(pitch)*np.sin(roll),np.cos(pitch)*np.cos(roll)]
```

Because of the nature of the gestures being investigated I am able to set yaw = 0. I thought with this I would be able to find a work around for a method of subtracting $g$ and obtaining linear acceleration.

Comment: The problem is, you will have no idea which direction `g` is in, and so you'll have to guess (and probably guess wrong).

Comment: Can you elaborate, @KendallFrey ?

Comment: As I said on Stack Overflow, there's no way to tell how strongly you're being influenced by gravity, and in what direction. The only data you have is acceleration relative to the device orientation, which isn't enough to determine anything related to gravity. Unless you can disprove General Relativity.

Comment: Sorry just struggling a little with this. It is possible to find the device orientation regarding to pitch and roll if it is stationary using the accelerometers output. Tilt sensing for stationary objects with accelerometers is simple.

Comment: You can't determine whether an object is stationary or not using only an accelerometer, so you have to either assume it is or assume it isn't.

Comment: Very well. If we assume it is not stationary how would one proceed?

Comment: Well, you'll have to make some assumptions. You could assume that gravity is in the same direction as the current acceleration. You could assume that the device is level. You could assume any number of things. You're simply trying to calculate too many unknowns from your known variables. Your problem is underspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no engineering background, so if anything I write is in error, definitely point it out.

However, if the 3-axis accelerometer only returns the proper acceleration vector $\mathbf{a}$, then if the object is moving around and physically accelerating, it is impossible to determine the orientation of the object without additional information.

Here is a formal counterexample.

#### State 1: Object at rest, roll is $\pi/4$, pitch is 0

The object experiences a proper acceleration vector of
$$\mathbf{a}=\left(0,\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

#### State 2: Object accelerating, roll is 0, pitch is 0

With an inertial acceleration vector $\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=\left(0,\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$, the proper acceleration measured will be
$$\mathbf{a}=\left(0,0,g\right)+\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=\left(0,\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{g}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Since both State 1 and State 2 return the same acceleration vector but have different spatial orientations, the act of converting proper acceleration to orientation under the influence of an outside acceleration is not a one-to-one correspondence, and thus is underdetermined.

In other words: how is the accelerometer supposed to tell the difference between State 1 and State 2? It can't, unless you have additional information.